# Is it possible to run the desired program in the terminal with the command?

Tags: autorun

If possible, what command should be used to run the programs?

Comment: Yes ... What is the desired program ?

Comment: For example, Vim program

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Just write vim in the terminal and press <Enter>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For terminal programs the command to run the program is usually the same as the package name of the program. For example, the package name of Vim is vim (with a lowercase v), and the command to start Vim is also `vim` (also with a lowercase v).

For launching GUI applications you don't need to know the package name of the app because you can launch the application by clicking its icon in the Dash.